# Delete action success message

Tags: javascript, react-redux, immutable.js

I have a delete action being performed when item(s) are deleted. Right now, whenever an item is deleted, I get a single message on screen. 
When I select multiple items to delete, I get a bunch of messages. For example, if I delete 3 items, the message saying "Video was deleted successfully." appears 3 times on the screen. How can I group all the messages into one based on the success response and show something like "3 videos got deleted successfully." and another message that would show "2 videos could not be deleted" ? With the code below, it shows either success or error result but not both. The error does not calculate how many failed.Here is what I have:

```
export function idsToDelete (ids) {
return dispatch => {
    const promises = ids.map(id => api.delete(dispatch, id));
    dispatch({
      type: DELETE,
      promise: Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
        console.log(results.size +"Video deleted.");
       }, error => {
          if(error.type) {
           console.log("video could not be deleted.");
        } else {
          return Promise.reject();
        }
      })
    });
  };
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can map all promises into array and then pass `Promise.all()` as promise:

```
const deletePromises = ids.map(id => api.delete(dispatch, id))
dispatch({
  type: DELETE_MANY,
  ids,
  promise: Promise.all(deletePromises)
    .then((results) => {
      // Show the success message only if delete was successful.
      console.log("Videos deleted successfully.");
    }, error => {
        return Promise.reject();
      }
    })
})
```

Comment: I tried your solution. Facing some issues, updated my code above. Please let me know what is going wrong.

Comment: What issues are you facing?

Comment: With the above code, it shows either success or error result but not both. The error does not calculate how many failed.

Comment: @Mustang in that case you can catch errors inside `Promise.all` and look for them in `results`. For example map promises like this `ids.map(id => api.delete(dispatch, id).catch(err => ({ err })))`